# how to get current function name where it is defined as part of an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

Is there a way to get current function name where it is defined as part of an object?
I know there is this way to get function name where its standalone function.

**function definition :**

```
function funName(){}
```

**get function name :**

```
var myName = arguments.callee.toString();
   myName = myName.substr('function '.length);
   myName = myName.substr(0, myName.indexOf('('));
```

**but how can I get it when it defined like :**

```
myobj.prototype.funcName = function(){}
```

Thanks.

Comment: `function(){}` is anonymous so it won't have a name.

Comment: what is the use of this ? if you can give more details of what you are trying to achieve, others will be able to suggest better solution.

Comment: but like @tracevipin said, what are you up to?, is this for a `logger`/debug  purposes, maybe you are aiming for something different which can be solved easier, It would be nice if you could provide a little more context

Comment: Hi, You guessed correctly, I need it for logger.

Answer (score 3):

As you are using an anonymous function, the only idea that comes to my mind is using something like a helper function, which

- Throws an dummy Error
- Catches It
- Parses the `stacktrace`
- returns an object with the parsed information in it

If its for debugging, this might be eligible, but i would restrain from using it in an productive environment as i don't really know whether throwing errors, parsing them. is such an good idea.

*Oh and just as a note, you shouldn't use `arguments.callee` as it is bad practice and even forbidden in `ECMAScript 5's` strict mode

you can simply name you function expressions*

[MDN arguments.callee:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee#Example.3A_Using_arguments.callee_in_an_anonymous_recursive_function)

> Note: You should avoid using arguments.callee() and just give every function (expression) a name.
>   Warning: The 5th edition of ECMAScript forbids use of arguments.callee() in strict mode.

Thats what i came up with on the first try *i only tested it on the latest `IE` `Firefox` `Chrome` so you may need to adjust the code*

```
var stackTest = function () {
    console.log(getStack(0).fn); //stackTest
}

function getStack(n) {
    var stacks = [];
    try {
        throw new Error("Test")
    } catch (e) {
        var stack = e.stack.split("\n");
        for (var i = 0, j = stack.length; i < j; i++) {
            var current = stack[i].match(/^(?:\s*at? ?)?(.+?)(?:@| )\(?(.*?):[^\/](\d*):?(\d*)?/)
            if (current == null) {
                continue
            }
            var entry = {
                fn: current[1] || "anonymous",
                file: current[2] || "unknown",
                line: ~~current[3],
                column: ~~current[4],
                time: new Date().getTime()
            }
            if ("getStack" !== entry.fn) stacks.push(entry);
        }
    } finally {
        return "number" === typeof n ? stacks[n] : stacks;
    }
}
stackTest();
```

Heres an example output, using an Object's prototype function

```
function test() {}
test.prototype.anotherTest = function () {
    console.log(getStack(0).fn);
  //Chrome:      "test.anotherTest"
  //Firefox:     "test.prototype.anotherTest"
  //IE:          "anotherTest"
}
var instance = new test();
instance.anotherTest();
```

Also an example on [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/erowew/2/edit):

Comment: Looks like the only option in strict mode.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var k in myobj.prototype){
    console.log(k)
```

}